# What does Profile > Preferences > I'm open to employers (not recruiters) contacting me do?

Tags: support, preferences

In my profile, under the Preferences tab, I have the option:

> I'm open to employers (not recruiters) contacting me

What does this do?
What have I opted in to by checking this?
What, if anything, changes as a result of this?

Answer (score 4):

It allows companies to contact you with a job offer which, based on how reputation on stackoverflow works, might be a good way to acquire talent.

Since the contacts are private, this would not be possible unless you explicitly select that option. Furthermore, since it does mention that recruiters aren't allowed, I believe the pool of authorized employers only includes technology based companies and excludes recruitment agencies. This way you will not be contacted by people that "might" have an offer for you in the "can't tell you yet" company.

Answer (score 1):

My educated guess would be that employers will be able to contact you if they are interested in hiring you.  Since you email is private, maybe there is/going to be a way for them to send you an email from this site.